# Concatenating Julia multi-dim arrays

Tags: julia

I'm really confused about how to properly concatenate julia arrays. I have an array (sim1.value) that is 4875x3x4. I would like to collapse it over the last dimension so that is is 19500x3.

`vcat(sim1.value)` and `cat(3,sim1.value)` don't give the result I want.

Comment: have you tried reshape?

Comment: Thanks I got what I wanted with reshape :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vcat(args)` command is like an abbreviation for `cat(1,args)` as it concatenates the given `args` on the vertical axis (the 1st dimension of your array)

You can get more information on that topic following this link: http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/#concatenation

Therefore, you can find a solution without using the `reshape` function:

```
# Get the size of your data 
x, y, z = size(data)

# Create a "result matrix" with the same number of columns, but no lines
result = similar(data, 0, y)

# For each layer, concatenate the layer verticaly with the "result matrix"
for i in 1:z
    result = vcat(result, data[:,:,z])
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the information and explanation, I understand what I was doing wrong now. Reshape ended up being a function more suited to do what I want.